# How to log data from response

Tags: ruby, graphql

I am working on graphql thing in Ruby. i am getting the response in the below format. But I would like to log the `status`, `accountId` from entire response. Can you please tell me how?

Response is:

```
#<GraphQL::Client::Response:0x000000010e536d08 @original_hash={"data"=>{"provisioningAddEntitlementToAccounts"=>{"result"=>[{"accountId"=>11571809, "status"=>"SUCCESS"}, {"accountId"=>11571810, "status"=>"SUCCESS"}, {"accountId"=>11571811, "status"=>"SUCCESS"}]}}}
```

I tried in the below formats

```
logger.info("Respoonse is: #{response.inspect}")

logger.info("Respoonse is: #{response.original_hash.inspect}")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
logger.info "accountId is: #{@original_hash['data']['provisioningAddEntitlementToAccounts']['result']['accountId']}"

logger.info "status is: #{@original_hash['data']['provisioningAddEntitlementToAccounts']['result']['status']}"
```